# Adding metadata to Seurat object

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have a Seurat object of 8 patients. I want to add metadata to that so that I have origin of each cell. At the moment UMAP just shows a bunch of cells while I want to color clusters by sample

This is my metadata

```
> str(head(metadata))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ barcodes: chr  "AAACAGCCAAACTGCC-5" "AAACAGCCAACAGGAT-1" "AAACAGCCAAGATTCT-1" "AAACAGCCAAGGTATA-1" ...
 $ libcodes: Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 5 1 1 1 5 7
 $ samples : chr  "PN0252_0005" "PN0252_0001" "PN0252_0001" "PN0252_0001" ...
> 

> pbmc
An object of class Seurat 
36601 features across 26473 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (36601 features, 0 variable features)
> 

> dim(metadata)
[1] 26473     3
>
```

Comment: Thanks @angel much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single-dimension per-cell metadata, and it's arranged identically to the cell order in the Seurat object, I find it easier to use the double bracket notation to add metadata to a Seurat object. For example:

```
metadata$barcodes -> pbmc[["barcodes"]]
metadata$libcodes -> pbmc[["libcodes"]]
metadata$samples -> pbmc[["samples"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from @user438383, converted from comment:*

Did you try [the AddMetaData function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Seurat/versions/3.1.4/topics/AddMetaData)? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279766/add-metadata-to-seurat-object) may also be useful.

```
cluster_letters <- LETTERS[Idents(object = pbmc_small)]
names(cluster_letters) <- colnames(x = pbmc_small)
pbmc_small <- AddMetaData(
  object = pbmc_small,
  metadata = cluster_letters,
  col.name = 'letter.idents'
)
```