# Seurat Dimplot with different clustering IDs

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics

In Seurat metadata I have assigned cells to some cell types with different resolutions

I have added the cluster identities to the object via `Idents`:

```
 Idents(control) <- a$predicted.celltype.l1
```

[image]

I then added another clustering in the same way:

```
 Idents(control) <- a$predicted.celltype.l2
```

Dimplot will now show the new identities:

[image]

How I can ask Dimplot to plot the clustering I want for example if I want to show `predicted.celltype.l1` again (something like changing the default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to tweak is the `group.by` argument of the `Dimplot` function.

It looks like you've already tried this in your attempts at solving [a different problem](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16332/color-by-clusters-and-sampled-in-seurat).

The main thing you need to be aware of is that each new clustering needs to be saved as a separate metadata variable in order to do this. As I mentioned in one of my [previous answers](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/16337/73), I like to use the `[[X]]` notation for this:

```
control[["predicted.celltype.l1"]] <- a$predicted.celltype.l1
control[["predicted.celltype.l2"]] <- a$predicted.celltype.l2
```

Then you should be able to use both in the `group.by` argument:

```
DimPlot(control, reduction = "umap", group.by = "predicted.celltype.l1")
DimPlot(control, reduction = "umap", group.by = "predicted.celltype.l2")
```